# How to update one table based on another one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have these two tables:

```
// user
+----+-------+------------+
| id |  name | total_rep  |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | Jack  | 100        |
| 2  | Peter | 334        |
| 3  | John  | 1          |
| 4  | Ali   | 5463       |
+----+-------+------------+

// rep
+----+------------+---------+------+
| id | reputation | id_user | done |
+----+------------+---------+------+
| 1  | 5          | 2       | 1    |
| 2  | 2          | 3       | 1    |
| 3  | 15         | 2       | Null |
| 4  | 10         | 2       | Null |
| 5  | 5          | 4       | 1    |
| 6  | 10         | 3       | Null |
+----+------------+---------+------+
```

I'm trying to sum the number of `reputation` column from `rep` table where `done` is `Null` for specific user and then add it to `total_rep` column from `user` table. So it is **expected output:**

```
// specific user
$id = 2;

// user
+----+-------+------------+
| id |  name | total_rep  |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | Jack  | 100        |
| 2  | Peter | 359        | -- this is updated
| 3  | John  | 1          |
| 4  | Ali   | 5463       |
+----+-------+------------+
```

**Note:** Then I will update `done` column and set all `Null` values for that user to `1`. *(this is not my question, I can do that myself)*

How can I do that?

Comment: Search on SO for "mysql update group by" queries. Seems like you can achieve your goal with subquery, where you will do grouping on `rep`, and after that you will join it to `user` table and update it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the result of a subquery as a [scalar value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/scalar-subqueries.html) in an update statement.

```
UPDATE `user` 
SET total_rep = total_rep + (
    SELECT SUM(reputation) AS rep_sum FROM `rep` WHERE done IS NULL AND id_user = 2)
WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: That's correct .. upvote .. Also I think we can do that by a `join` instead of that subquery. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible as well. I'm not enough of an expert to discuss performance of one vs. the other, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update two tables in one statement, so you will need to execute a transaction. Or maybe in some code do the next thing I'll make it in PHP

```
$query_result=DB::select('Select sum(reputation) as reputation, id_user from rep where done is null group by id_user');

foreach($query_result as $result){
    //update the data
}
```

You have to take the data and update firstable the reputation table to clean it and then the user table to sum the rep values